# How to start OWASP Shepherd using Docker?

Tags: owasp, docker

I have pulled the [Security Shepherd Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ismisepaul/securityshepherd/) and followed all the instructions for the Docker setup. I believe all steps were successful.

Now I don't know how to run the Shepherd application, while the Docker image is running. I assumed it would be something similar to the VM - connect from a browser to the IP address of the image, but I get a timeout...

How could I start the Shepherd?

Comment: It looks according to the documentation that it should bind to port 80 and 443. Did you try https?

Comment: Yes... After a warning that the site is not secure (?) I get redirected to the Apache Tomcat homepage from `https://localhost:443` and to a "Site can't provide a secure connection" error from `https://localhost:80` ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of how did you run the container. If you specified `-p` option, then you mapped ports from your host to the container in order to access it directly on your localhost. I mean, for example, if you put on docker run command `-p 5555:80`, you are mapping container port 80 to host's port 5555, so you can access to it on `http://localhost:5555`.

If you don't want to map ports in order to prevent anyone on your network can access to the container through your host, run it without `-p`and then you can do a `docker inspect` command to find the container ip address. Because the containers by default are accessible only by the host machine on a specific ip. Docker set iptables on run and allow only to you to access to the container. You can do `docker inspect yourContainerName | grep '"IPAddress"' | head -n 1` and you'll get the ip address of your container. Then you can access **only from the host** to `http://<yourResultIpFromBeforeCmd>`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I did specify the -p option, with 80:80 and 443:443 but neither localost:443 nor localhost:80 work. Also, `$ docker inspect ismisepaul/securityshepherd | grep '"IPAddress"'` doesn't print anything. Looked through the result of `$ docker inspect ismisepaul/securityshepherd` (no grep) and indeed there's no IPAddress there... :(

Comment: So the problem is of your image or container. This is not a docker itself problem. Your docker container is not well configured. Maybe the image is not ok or you are not configuring it well.

Comment: It finally worked. After switching from windows 8 to windows 10 and modifying the command to start the container to `docker run -i -p 82:80 -p 444:443 ismisepaul/securityshepherd /bin/bash` (because ports 80 and 443 were automatically assigned to Tomcat), I could connect to the service running in docker on `https://localhost:444`. Thank you for your help, the ports hint and `docker inspect` were useful.

Answer (score 1):

When running Docker on some flavors of Windows it runs in a Virtualbox instance so you'd need to look up Docker's ip, then connect to http://docker.ip.ad.dr:port, not localhost.

There may be a more Docker-ey way to do it, but I always just look it up using ipconfig. On my pc it shows up as "Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network", typically in the 192.168.99.x range.

See  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482154/can-i-run-windows-containers-using-docker-toolbox-on-windows-7) and [docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install).